# White spaces around IEEEbiography at IEEE Journal Template

Tags: ieeetran

There are four co-author biographies at the end of my paper. There are some white spaces among them. I am trying to get rid of them. Is there a way to do it other than -vspace, because I guess it will also cause more problems as I add/remove things from previous pages

Answer (score 15):

You have basically two simple tools.

- You need to push them together with `\vspace{-x mm}` and use `\newpage` to break the column.
- Also to keep them spreading apart on the same column you have to put `\enlargethispage{-9.5cm}` after the last entry on the last page.

It always needs tweaks but you don't need to worry as IEEE will ruin your article after receiving the master copy anyway (Confirmed many times by my own experience!).

Comment: \vfill does this hob columnwise, but still not the right answer

Comment: @sosruko I didn't mention `\vfill` and it is not the way to go here.