# IEEEtran - Large white space between bibliography and author biographies

Tags: ieeetran

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [White spaces around IEEEbiography at IEEE Journal Template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75891/white-spaces-around-ieeebiography-at-ieee-journal-template)

I am writing a document using the IEEEtran class. The bibliography spills from the second column on one page over to the first column on the next page and continues 1/3rd the way down the column. After this comes 7 author biographies. However the first author's biography is printed at the bottom of the first column and the rest are printed in the second column, leaving a large white space. e.g.

```
+------------------------------------------+
| ref ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~    bio 2 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
| ref ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~    bio 2 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
| ref ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~                      |
| ref ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~    bio 3 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
| ref ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~    bio 3 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
| ref ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~                      |
| ref ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~    bio 4 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
| ref ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~    bio 4 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
|                                          |
|                        bio 5 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
|                        bio 5 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
|                                          |
|                        bio 6 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
|                        bio 6 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
|                                          |
|                        bio 7 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
|                        bio 7 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
| bio 1 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~                        |
| bio 1 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~                        |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: probably bio1 and bio2 don't fit together but bio1 itself can't fill the first column.  Try making the bios and references get closer to each other by introducing negative space via `\vspace{-x cm}` such that it's not recognizable but enough to push bio2 to the left. By the way, if this is for the final submission you don't need to worry because the proof office will make the final tweaks anyway.

Comment: There is more than enough white space for bio 2 to fit in the first column. If I remove all bios except 1 and 2 they both end up on the first column. I didn't mention is that the last bio actually ends up on the page after this, all by itself. Doesnt change what happens if it is removed though. \vspace didn't work unfortunately. Good to know that the proof office will fix it. :)

Comment: Maybe it's best to put a `\newpage` after bio2 and bio6. See this one : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75891/white-spaces-around-ieeebiography-at-ieee-journal-template?rq=1

Comment: It's probably better to make it as a duplicate of the other one :)

Comment: @percusse Thanks, but I disagree. My question involved bio1 stuck in one column. Also the correct answer (use \newpage) is not in your answer for the last question.

Comment: Hmm, we can reopen it if you want but I've mentioned `\newpage` in the other question too. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could just issue \vskip 0pt plus -1fil between the two IEEEbiography elements (to negative the inserted 1fil). If you want them closer to one another, adjust 0pt to something like -2\baselineskip.

So can do \vskip -2\baselineskip plus -1fil